# Link to specific part of page

Tags: html, ios, wordpress, safari

I've tried all of the following:

```
<a name="test"></a>
<a id="test"></a>
<h4 id="test">SOME TEXT</h4>
```

And then linking to them like this:

```
<a href="pagename#test">
```

All of the above work with Firefox, IE and Chrome, but none of them worked with Safari 5.xx on a mac. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: The above is **not** valid HTML. There should be only **one** element with a specific id value in a page. Your has two with `test`.

Comment: I tried one at a time of course. Sorry for not making that clear.

Comment: Please post a self-contained demo document that illustrates the problem. It seems that the issue is not in the code snippets you posted but elsewhere in the document.

Answer (score 8):

`<a href="#test">Go to Test</a>`

.
.
.

`<div id="test">This is Test.</div>`

This should work.

EDITED:
Also, if you want to link to a particular id in a different page, which I think you do, use:

`<a href="somepage.html#test">Go to Test on some different page.</a>`

Comment: i tried now on safari 5.1.14, it worked.. not sure why it is not working for  you.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a misunderstanding of how anchors work, you need to use the `href` attribute.

```
<a name="test"></a>          <!-- not required -->
<a id="test"></a>            <!-- not required -->
<h4 id="test">SOME TEXT</h4> <!-- this is correct -->
```

To link to the `<h4 id="test">` element do this (if target on the same page):

```
<a href="#test">Go to Test</a>
```

If target on a different page:

```
<a href="other_page.html#test">
```